# awk column replacement, but line numbrs are different between files

Tags: replace, awk

I want to replace 3, 4 and 5th columns of  lines from 20 to 100 of file a.com with 6, 7 , 8th columns of lines from 50 to 130 of file b.com. I know the command

```
awk 'NR==FNR {fld6[NR]=$6; fld7[NR]=$7; fld8[NR]=$8; next}
FNR>19 && FNR<101 {$3=fld6[FNR]; $4=fld7[FNR]; $5=fld8[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
```

-will work if the line numbers were same (20 to 100) for a.com b.com, but here they are not (20 to 100 for a.com and 50 to 130 for b.com). So I how to replace column of files with different line numbers using awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add 30 to `FNR`:

```
FNR>19 && FNR<101 {$3=fld6[FNR+30]; $4=fld7[FNR+30]; $5=fld8[FNR+30]}
```